# Why is a picture appearing blurry on the iphone (no scaling)

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

I have been doing a bit of testing with images today and found that I could not make a blurry PNG image, which looked fine on my desktop appear non-blurry on the iphone without doing some strange things.

It wasn't until I made the images twice the resolution, then resized them within the iphone that they appeared crisp on screen. Is that normal practice?

What say if you have a background image that you want to be non-blurry? I don't see how I can do something like upload a background image and tell it to run at half the size...

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: What model iPhone are you testing it on?

Comment: Actually currently just testing on an ipod running 5.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer.

It turns out that pixels are not the same on the iphone and are actually at a higher resolution.

In order to make images non-blurry, I needed to basically upload images 2-3 times regular size and then make their size smaller within the CSS.

For example, if I wanted a 50px image, I uploaded a 100px image and styled in within css to have a width of 50px.

It looks like the new iPads have even higher resolutions which means you may even want to upload higher resolution images to cater to those.

A bit lame I think, but it does look nice.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding you, but if you'd like to present a crisp image on a retina phone, you can place it in a UIImageView half it's size and set the contentMode to scale to fill.

Comment: Sorry, I maybe didn't explain very well. This is really just a jquery mobile web page, not an actual app.